# How put a blur effect in the background of back button in navigationcontroller

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I ve found some similar question on StackOverFlow, but it's slightly different.

I ve got a translucent navigation bar with a back button.
But as you can see on the screenshot of the app, it's hard to see the back button ("Retour"). So how could i change the background's color of the back button ?
I will apply a blur effect in there.

I ve tried a lot of thing, but that change the color of the whole navigation bar... not just the backbutton

Here's my code :

```
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

[image: Screenshot of the app]

I found this. But i couldn't apply my blur effect, no ?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your image name"),
 forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: this controller is presented. right???
your code works great only when you push this viewController instead present.

Comment: yes, but it's translucent/transparent. I m wondering if i need to create a custom UIview and add it , without using navigation bar.

Comment: yess....excactly

Comment: such a waste of time... thx mate